# Django form and i18n

Tags: django, forms, internationalization

I have forms that I want to display in different languages : I used the label parameter to set a parameter, and used ugettext() on the labels :

```
agreed_tos = forms.BooleanField(label=ugettext('I agree to the terms of service and to the privacy policy.'))
```

But when I am rendering the form in my template, using

```
{{form.as_p}}
```

The labels are not translated. Does somebody have a solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use [`ugettext_lazy()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/internationalization/#lazy-translation):

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy

# ... 
  agreed_tos = forms.BooleanField(label=ugettext_lazy('I agree to the terms of service and to the privacy policy.'))
```

Model and form attributes are initialized when your Django application starts. If you use `ugettext()`, the translation will be set once at initialization and never change. `ugettext_lazy()` solves this problem by translating the string when its value is accessed rather than when the function is called.

Comment: Apparently the important bit is that ugettext_lazy has the context of the logged in user/session.