# Translations not persisting in Django

Tags: django, session, translation

I've spent quite a few hours searching this site and other sites, and reading the Django documentation, but I have not yet been able to find a solution for my Django translation problem. I should add that I am a Django newbie, so apologise in advance if I'm doing something silly.

I am using Django 1.10 and Python 3.5.2.

**My situation**

Every registered user for my application will have a language code assigned. This code will be stored in an extension of the `django.contrib.auth.models` `User` model (so `UserExtend` model, with 1-1 mapping to `User`). When a user logs in, I would like to read this language code and consequently translate all pages the user visits into that language. To do this, I am activating translations and storing the language code in a session variable. However, I find that after the user logs in and is redirected to another page, strings are not translated. If I log the user in but omit the redirection code (ie just present the login page again), strings **are** translated (I check this by creating a user with `language_code` `'de-DE'` and creating and compiling dummy translations with _de prefixes), but as soon as I use my menus to go elsewhere, we're back to English again.

**My assumptions:**

According to the Django doc [(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference):

> `LocaleMiddleware` tries to determine the user’s language preference by following this algorithm:
>
> First, it looks for the language prefix in the requested URL. This is only performed when you are using the `i18n_patterns` function in your root `URLconf`. See Internationalization: in URL patterns for more information about the language prefix and how to internationalize URL patterns.
>
> Failing that, it looks for the `LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY` key in the current user’s session.
>
> Failing that, it looks for a `cookie`. (So, I had to flag cookie as code because the editor wouldn't let me post unless I did....)
>
> The name of the cookie used is set by the `LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME` setting. (The default name is `django_language`.)
>
> Failing that, it looks at the Accept-Language HTTP header. This header is sent by your browser and tells the server which language(s) you prefer, in order by priority. Django tries each language in the header until it finds one with available translations.
>
> Failing that, it uses the global `LANGUAGE_CODE` setting.

From this, I believe that I should be able to achieve global translation of my project using sessions, and NOT `i18n_patterns`.

Also from the Django doc (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#explicitly-setting-the-active-language), apparently the following code should be enough to persist my translation language.

```
from django.utils import translation
user_language = 'fr'
translation.activate(user_language)
request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = user_language
```

It does not appear to do so. Note that if I add code like this to the top of all my views, then I do actually get translations persisting, unless my template embeds a form. Forms don't seem to know about requests, and so they just always seem to keep the English translation.

**My code:**

*settings.py:*

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


# Authentication
## Not sure if these two are necessary, but one of the many tutorials I've been looking at suggested I do them.

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/' # It means home view
LOGIN_URL = 'login'

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-AU'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LANGUAGES = (
('en', _('English')),
('de', _('German')),
)
```

*Definition of menus in base.html*

```
<div class="nav navbar-nav pull-md-right">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {# Translators: Welcome message, of the form "Welcome, [user's first name] [user's surname]!" #}
            <span class="nav-item nav-link text-muted">{% blocktrans with first_name=user.first_name last_name=user.last_name %}Welcome, {{ first_name }} {{ last_name }}!{% endblocktrans %}</span>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">{% trans "Sign out" %}</a>
    {% else %}
<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">{% trans "Register" %}</a>
<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">{% trans "Sign in" %}</a>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

*login.html:*

```
{% extends 'appname/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title_block %}{% trans "Sign in" %}{% endblock %}

{% block header_block %}
  <link href="{% static 'css/login.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}


{% block body_block %}
  <div class="container">
{% if form.errors %}
  <div class="form-signin alert-danger">
<!-- Display this message even for an inactive account. -->
{% trans "Your login details were invalid. Please try again." %}
  </div>
{% endif %}
{% if next %}
<div class="form-signin alert-danger">
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
{% trans "Your account doesn't have access to this page. To proceed, please login with an account that has access." %}
  {% else %}
{% trans "Please log in to see this page." %}
  {% endif %}
</div>
{% endif %}  
<form class="form-signin" method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <h2 class="form-signin-heading">{% trans "Please sign in" %}</h2>
{{ form.username.label_tag}}
{{ form.username }}
{{ form.password.label_tag}}
{{ form.password }}
  <div class="checkbox">
      <!-- Not yet implemented. Probably stick this into the form as well. -->
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> {% trans "Remember me" %}
</label>
  </div>
  <div class="">
Forgot login
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">{% trans "Sign in" %}</button>
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

*views.py:*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import translation
from django.utils.translation import LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY
from django import forms
from appname.forms import LoginForm

def index(request):
    # Hack. I'm sure this is not the right thing to do.
    user_language = request.session.get(LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY)
    translation.activate(user_language)

    # Do stuff

    return render(request, 'appname/index.html', context=context_dict)


def login_user(request):
    user_language = request.session.get(LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY)
    translation.activate(user_language)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LoginForm(request, data=request.POST)
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        if form.is_valid():
            fw_username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            fw_password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=fw_username, password=fw_password)
            if user is not None and user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                user_language = user.extended.language_code.language_code
                translation.activate(user_language)
                request.session[LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = user_language
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()   # Display unbound form

    return render(request, 'appname/login.html', { 'form': form })


def us(request):
    # Hack. I'm sure this is not the right thing to do.
    user_language_code = request.session.get(LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY)
    translation.activate(user_language_code)

    return render(request, 'appname/us.html')
```

*project/urls.py:*

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from appname import views
from appname.forms import LoginForm

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^appname/', include('appname.urls')), # Any URLs starting with appname are to be handled by the mindatot app
   # url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'appname/login.html', 'authentication_form': LoginForm}, name='login'),
url(r'^login/$', views.login_user, name='login'),
url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': 'login'}, name='logout'),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

*forms.py:*

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm 
from django import forms
from django.utils import translation
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

# If you don't do this you cannot use Bootstrap CSS
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    # I'm confused. How do I translate this one?
    #user_language = session.get(LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY)
    #translation.activate(user_language)

    username = forms.CharField(label=_("Username"), max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'username'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"), max_length=30, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'password'}))
```

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE 12/10/2016:**
I happened upon the following Stack Overflow question [Django form and i18n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694798/django-form-and-i18n), and that has sorted out my form translation issue (`uggettext_lazy` gets request and session information, it seems).

So my only question now is, do I really have to do translation.activate and grab the language code from the session every view? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure sessions persist? How have you set `SESSIONS_ENGINE`? Do you have `django.contrib.sessions` in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Yes, `django.contrib.sessions` is in INSTALLED_APPS. I have not set `SESSION_ENGINE`, however as I understand, Django stores sessions in the database by default without specifying this setting and there are records in my `django_session` MySQL table. When I put the code `request.session.get(LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY)` into my `index` and `us` views, the language I set on login is returned, which implies to me the sessions are persisting?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that when I run `translation.get_language()` rather than `request.session.get(LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY)`, it always just returns `en`. Which in itself I find a bit weird, given that my default `LANGUAGE_CODE` is `en-au`.

Comment: I just had a look at the Django documentation again, and this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/#configuring-the-session-engine) states that 'If you want to use a database-backed session, you need to add `'django.contrib.sessions'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Once you have configured your installation, run `manage.py` migrate to install the single database table that stores session data.' So, no need to set `SESSION_ENGINE` unless I want to do something other than the default, I think. Thanks again for your reply!

Comment: As a further update, I've been trying to integrate the django-allauth registration and login package, and for the life of me I cannot get the pages in that to translate. So my approach must be incorrect. There must be something I'm missing.